# How to change the username in linux?

Tags: linux, process

I need to change the username from the linux (**Not admin**).

I changed in settings ->Users. But how to change the "home folder" name or root user in linux.

I tried using

`usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>`

But this always mentions that
`username <oldname> is currently used by process <some id>`

Does anything happen if I kill the process?

I logged into root also as "su -" and tried the same "usermod" command.

So, how do I change the name without killing the process?

Any leads will be appreciated. I have attached a photo of changed username in settings->users.

[username change in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSF2P.png)

Regards,
Sunag R A.

Comment: Please note that [cross-posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333371/how-to-change-the-username-in-ubuntu-18-04) is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Command you are using is correct. For reference you can also see the following url,

https://linuxtechlab.com/rename-user-in-linux-rename-home-directory/

The problem might be that you might be logged in as the user that you are trying to rename or that user has process running. So first thing is to be a user that you are not updating (root user is good option) and then you can kill all the process running for a user with the following command,

pkill -U UID

where UID is the user id. Or you can also use,

pkill -U username

Or

killall -u username

And then you should run the user mod command to rename the user.

Hope this helps.